# How can I ul size relative to header?

Tags: html, css

I have a list with their respective hyperlinks. I want these elements to be the same size as the header. I tried adding an auto padding but it didn't work, I also tried adding a height auto, but it didn't work either.

This is my html:

```
<header id="header" class="header">
      <nav id="nav" class="nav">
         <div id="brand" class="brand">
            <img src="" alt="GEM Logo" />
         </div>
         <ul id="nav__menu" class="nav__menu">
            <li><a href="/company">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="/solutions">Solutions</a></li>
            <li><a href="/team">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="/aboutus">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/support">Support</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>
```

and this is my sass:

```
@import "_variables.scss";

.header {
   background-color: $primary-color;
   color: white;
   padding: 20px;

   & a{
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
   }
}

.header .nav {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;

   & .nav__menu {
      display: flex;

      & li {
        margin-right: 15px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
      }

      & li:hover {
         animation: headerLinks;
         animation-duration: 2s;
      }
   }
}

@keyframes headerLinks {
   from {
      border: none;
   }
   to {
      border: 1px solid red;
   }
}
```

[image]

That is the result I have, and that's fine. But I need that element **li** and element **a** have the same size as the header. Since what I want to achieve is an animation when the user makes a hover, and that the background of the element changes.

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly want. Would you like that the HEIGHT of the **li** have the same as the header height? Should the background of the **li** changed on hover? You animate here the border...

Comment: Yes, I was animating the border to test the size of the element. @LeventeGabos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't define padding-top and bottom on '.header' if you want that the 'li' items to have the same height like the header. Your css should looks like below. Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z8cwrkho/).

```
 .header {
    background-color: #00f;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 20px;

    & a{
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
   }
 }

 .header .nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    & .brand {
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
 }

 & .nav__menu {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    & li {
      margin-right: 15px;
      padding: 20px 10px;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      list-style: none;
    }

    & li:hover {
       animation: headerLinks;
       animation-duration: 2s;
    }

 }

 @keyframes headerLinks {
     from {
        background-color: transparent;
     }
     to {
        background-color: #0f0;
     }
 }
```